# Scroll pages horizontally

Tags: jquery, scroll

Let's say, I have 3 pages. I need to build a website.
Instead of traditional vertical scrolling effect, I want to go for horizontal scrolling.
Can anyone guide my on achieving horizontal scroll keeping in mind that my website is not a single page, but it consists of multiple pages.
So, when a user scrolls the mouse, pages should change in a horizontal scroll effect, and the respective page name should appear in the URL also (it's for SEO purposes).
The scrolling effect can be achieved using AJAX/jQuery sliding effect.
How can this be achieved? Any code snippet or references?
All of the website that I have seen are of a single page. I don't want that.

For your reference, please see:
[www.black5.de](http://www.black5.de)

Answer (score 1):

I have specified a link below. This may help you. You may need to trigger some events when the scroll reaches particular position so that it is navigated to the next page.

https://designedbyaturtle.com/horizontal-scrolling-with-jquery/

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It will give me a kick start. :)